# Eclipse-Plugin: Program Counter position

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-cdt

I am about to break here into pieces. I asked in the forum community, I asked the developer list and I already asked on stackoverflow.

`Where is that code-line that just moves that program-counter annotation to that line that I want it to move?`

Speaking of highlighting the line which is currently executed during debug.

I've checked out

`org.eclipse.cdt.debug.core`

`org.eclipse.cdt.debug.ui`

`org.eclipse.cdt.dsf.gdb`

`org.eclipse.cdt.dsf.gdb.multicorevisualizer.ui`

`org.eclipse.cdt.dsf.gdb.ui`

`org.eclipse.cdt.tests.dsf.gdb`

`org.eclipse.cdt.ui`

`org.eclipse.cdt.visualizer.core`

`org.eclipse.cdt.visualizer.ui`

but I coldn't find a line that just does this.

```
foo = new ObjectThatDoesWhatINeed();
foo.highlightLine(lineNumber);`
```

I'm freaking out here since I stuck there for a week now and this should not be such a huge thing since I suppose that Eclipse is designed to re-use functionalities, right?

Answer (score 0):

How about adding a breakpointListener and then using AST to identify current cursor position?

From the extension point description (bold mark by me):

> Allow clients to contribute listeners for Java breakpoint
>   notifications. For example, listeners are **called when a breakpoint is
>   hit** and about to suspend execution. The listener can vote to resume or
>   suspend the debug session. Listeners can be programmatically added to
>   and removed from specific Java breakpoints (specified by breakpoint
>   listener identifers), or be registered to listen for notifications for
>   all Java breakpoints.

The Extension Point is called:

```
org.eclipse.jdt.debug.breakpointListeners
```

Comment: Well, I am using the CDT plugin since the program I want to debug is written in C. I am pretty sure that somewhere out there is a way to integrate a simple debug process and let Eclipse handle the UI stuff.

Answer (score 0):

That visualization is not specific to the CDT plugin, so you will surely find it in the generic org.eclipse.debug.ui instead.

Looking at the extensions defined in that plugins manifest.mf, there is an annotation type called org.eclipse.debug.ui.currentIP, which might be the one for the current instruction pointer. But this is just guessing.